# Getting started with django and heroku, "application error" after upload

Tags: python, django, heroku

1. I have been using this guide: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django

### requirements.txt

```
Django==1.6.5
argparse==1.2.1
dj-database-url==0.3.0
dj-static==0.0.5
django-toolbelt==0.0.1
gunicorn==18.0
psycopg2==2.5.3
pystache==0.5.4
static==1.0.2
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

---

### file structure

```
   hellodjango
   ├── hellodjango
   │   ├── __init__.py
   │   ├── settings.py
   │   ├── settings.py~
   │   ├── urls.py
   │   ├── wsgi.py
   │   └── wsgi.py~
   └── manage.py
   1 directory, 7 files
```

---

### other files in directory Projects/projects/6.2.2014

```
    (venv)user@user-VirtualBox:~/Projects/projects/6.2.2014$ ls
    hellodjango  Procfile  Procfile~  requirements.txt  venv
```

### A snippet from the heroku logs:

```
    2014-06-02T23:42:49.621172+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named  
    hellodjango.wsgi
    2014-06-02T23:42:49.621171+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
    2014-06-02T23:42:49.621219+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-06-02 23:42:49 [7] [INFO] Worker
    exiting (pid: 7)
    2014-06-02T23:42:49.790790+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-06-02 23:42:49 [2] [INFO] Shutting
    down: Master
    2014-06-02T23:42:51.344028+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
    2014-06-02T23:42:47.298345+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command 
    `gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi`
    2014-06-02T23:42:51.355014+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to 
    crashed
    (venv)user@user-VirtualBox:~/Projects/projects/6.2.2014$
```

### Procfile

```
    web: gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

Can anyone point me in the direction of what I'm missing here?
I had the same "application error" after visiting my site when the Procfile only had this:

### Procfile (old)

```
    web: gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi
```

### Settings file

```
    # Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
    import os
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


    # Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
    # See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

    # SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
    # I removed this line for the stack overflow posting SECRET_KEY = ''

    # SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
    DEBUG = True

    TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


    # Application definition

    INSTALLED_APPS = (
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'gunicorn', #this wasn't here before, i added it and still got the application 
         # error
        )

    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
       'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
     )

    ROOT_URLCONF = 'hellodjango.urls'

    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'hellodjango.wsgi.application'


    # Database
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

    """
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
     }
    """
    # Internationalization
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

    TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

    USE_I18N = True

    USE_L10N = True

    USE_TZ = True


    # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

    STATIC_URL = '/static/'

    # Parse database configuration from $DATABASE_URL
    import dj_database_url
    DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()

    # Honor the 'X-Forwarded-Proto' header for request.is_secure()
    SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')


    # Static asset configuration
    import os
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'

    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    )
```

### This is my current wsgi.py file in /Projects/projects/6.2.2014/hellodjango/hellodjango

```
    import os
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
    from dj_static import Cling
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "hellodjango.settings")


    application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```

Comment: What does your wsgi file look like? Also your requirements.txt file isn't in your project structure? Is that just a simple mistake or is it not checked into your git repo?

Comment: Just added that. You mean the wsgi.py file, right? The requirements.txt file is in same the folder as: {hellodjango  Procfile  Procfile~  requirements.txt  venv}. It was automatically created when I ran "pip freeze > requirements.txt" Did pip freeze put it in the wrong folder or was I in the wrong folder when I entered that command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your wsgi.py file to this:

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "hellodjango.settings")
from dj_static import Cling
application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```

You need to specify your settings before importing Cling otherwise it will error out.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `.wsgi` file

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from dj_static import Cling

application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I think I already have that in my wsgi.py file. I went ahead and edited the original post so everyone can see my current wsgi.py file.

Comment: make sure you are pushing from base directory of your project to heroku

Comment: Did you mean wsgi.py?

Comment: In my case, the base directory is within the folder "6.2.2014" right?

Comment: No, I mean while you push your app by "git push heroku master" give this command from .../6.2.2014/hellodjago i.e. the location where your manage.py is located

Comment: you base directory is where your manage.py is located in this case

Comment: Ah okay, trying that now. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: So, I restarted the entire tutorial in a new folder and followed each step, and when I ran foreman start the webpage looked fine. However, despite running "git push heroku master" in the correct directory, I still got the "application error" page after viewing the app in the browser.

Comment: hmm.. try skipping foreman start and follow all steps, because its just to start the processes in your Procfile locally.